# Debian 8 Jessie "E: Unable to locate package lmms"

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to install lmms for some audio production on Debian 8. Here's process:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install lmms
```

> "E: Unable to locate package lmms"

This is following these instructions: https://lmms.io/download/#linux

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150909-00:22]/ jessie contrib main non-free

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150909-00:22]/ jessie contrib main non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list`:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/jessie main
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of the following command? `head -n 40 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`

Comment: An alternative is `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: Fatheem what do you mean? Code example please?

Answer (score 9):

For some reason, your Debian installation is missing package sources. `/etc/apt/sources.list` only lists the installation CD and the security updates, but not the main online repository. Add the main online repository: edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` (as root, e.g. with `sudoedit`) and add the lines

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

You may want to replace `ftp.debian.org` by a [mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) closer to you. Order only matters if multiple sources have the exact same version (first APT determines which version to install, then it uses the first listed source that has this version).

Once this is done, run `sudo apt-get update` and install the packages you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are only getting packages from 3 repositories and none of them seem to contain the `lmms` package. Try adding this stanza to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, then rerun `apt-get update` and `apt-get install lmms`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score -2):

```
root@debian30:/# vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

comment the cd-rom lines:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 NETINST 20180310-11:55]/ stretch main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 NETINST 20180310-11:55]/ stretch main
```